# MYSQL Como colocar em ordem esse campo data

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um campom data com tuda data separada e preciso colocar em ordem como eu faço..segue exemplo que não esta funcionando...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mensagens` ORDER BY `ano`,`mes`,`dia` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

ele deixa em ordem mais não na ordem certa
os campos de data estão com a formatação de 2 dígitos em números, tipo 06 - 04 - 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `mensagens` order by date(concat(ano,'-', mes,'-',dia)) asc
```

Acredito que fazendo a junção com [`Concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), transformando em data com a função [`Date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) resolve seu problema ...

***Referências***

- [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: boa, funcionou!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para você utilizar datas em banco de dados o correto é ter um campo no formato datetime() (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) e então vc conseguirá fazer a ordenação por data.
Caso contrário, seu campo será tratado como string ou int (dependendo de que forma está os campos do banco).

No PHP você pode converter facilmente um campo em formato de data para salvar corretamente no banco utilizando a função date() (http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que converter essas colunas para um campo data com [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) resolva o problema de ordenação:

```
SELECT str_to_date(concat(ano,'-',mes,'-', dia), '%Y-%m-%d') as nova_data FROM datas 
ORDER BY nova_data ASC
```