# Como ordenar por data quando dia, mês e ano estão cada um em uma coluna?

Tags: php, mysql, data

Olá,

Estou com a seguinte situação, tenho que ordenar uma tabela por data, mas por algum motivo em particular o programador decidiu salvar o dia, mês e o ano em colunas separada, obs o banco esta em MySql, existe um procedimento eficaz para fazer tal ordenação?

Seria o correto utilizar ORDER BY dia, mes e ano ?

Grata.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12021/91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o tipo das colunas for inteiro basta fazer um `ORDER BY ANO, MES, DIA`. Caso esteja em formato textual, principalmente se tiver misturado valores com dois ou um dígito, verifique o link que o usuário "perdeu" colocou como comentário na sua pergunta.